# WDS install modifying BCD

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, deployment, windows-pe

### Situation

I am currently using **WDS** on a Windows Server  2012 R2 to deploy a **Windows to Go** disk.

The idea is to make it possible to deploy a **W2G** disk from any workstations, including computers with an operating system already installed.

### Issue

During the installation task of windows to go on an external drive, the task modifies the **BCD** file on the local drive, wich makes it impossible to boot on the local computer. I end up with a bluescreen of death.

I know it is the BCD file, because if I repair it, the workstation works again

### Question

Is there a way to get the installation task not to modify the BCD file?